# JNI call to Java function returning an Object results in NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a Java function which returns a singleton instance of a Class

```
public static synchronized MyClass getInstance() throws MyClassException{
    if (instance == NULL){
        // create
    } 
    return instance;
}
```

I want to call this through C++ code, but when I do, it returns a NoSuchMethodError.

```
cls = jenv->FindClass("MyClass");
if (cls == NULL)
{
//error handling
}
mid = jenv->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "getInstance", "()LMyClass");
if (mid == NULL)
{
//error handling
}
```

When I run:

```
javap -s -p on MyClass, I get the signature:
public static synchronized MyClass getInstance()   throws MyClassException;
Signature: ()LMyClass;
```

If I change the function signature to void in the Java class, the GetStaticMethodID call works as expected.

Do I need to setup a jobject to expect the return value from the call?

Is this possible without calling GetStaticMethodID first?

Comment: Where is the call that's returning the error?

Comment: When I run the C++ app, I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getInstance

Comment: I wonder if you need to specify the fully qualified path to "MyClass" in the call to GetStaticMethodId. For example:

jenv->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "getInstance", "()Lcom/work/MyClass;");

Depending on where the CPP code lives relative to the Java code? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that it's unable to resolve the output argument specified. If your java class were in the package: "com/work/", you would say:

```
jenv->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "getInstance", "()Lcom/work/MyClass;");
```

That should do it.

EDIT:

It looks like the answer is in the output of javap isn't it? You should be doing:

```
jenv->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "getInstance", "()LMyClass;");
```

Comment: Typo in my original question. I had this as **()LMyClass**

Comment: And you explicitly said "()LMyClass;" with the semi-colon at the end?

Comment: For example, I can do:

getStaticMethodID(cls, "currentThread", "()Ljava/lang/Thread;");

And that works fine. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yep - missed the semi-colon. Thanks!